# How do I make a button delete an item from array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently making a Library project, and I made it so that each book entered is stored in an array (in this case, the array is myLibrary). Then I made it so that each book in the array creates a new div with the class of "card." I've implemented a "Remove Button" for each card, but I'm not sure as to how I can make the button delete the book from the array. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

I've tried

```
const remBtn = document.createElement("button");
    card.appendChild(remBtn);
    remBtn.textContent = "Remove";
    remBtn.onclick = remBook;

// Remove book function
function remBook() {
  const findBook = myLibrary.findIndex((element) => element === book);
  const delBook = myLibrary.slice(findBook, 1);
}
```

Here are my codes:

html:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Library</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">Library</div>
    <form id="submitInput" action="">
      <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" id="formTitle" name="title" required />
      <label for="author">Author:</label>
      <input type="text" id="formAuthor" name="author" required />
      <label for="page">Page:</label>
      <input type="text" id="formPage" name="page" required />
      <div class="read">
        <label for="read">Read</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="formRead" name="read" value="" />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Add Book" />
    </form>
    <div class="currentDisplay"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// Data inputs

let myLibrary = [
  {
    title: "test",
    author: "test",
    page: "123",
    read: true,
  },
];

// Object constructor
function book(title, author, page, read) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.page = page;
  this.read = read;
}

// Add new books to library
function addBookToLibrary() {
  let a = document.getElementById("formTitle").value;
  let b = document.getElementById("formAuthor").value;
  let c = document.getElementById("formPage").value;
  let d = document.getElementById("formRead").checked;

  if (a !== "" && b !== "" && c !== "") {
    myLibrary.push(new book(a, b, c, d));
  }
}

const submit = document.getElementById("submitInput");
submit.addEventListener("submit", () => {
  event.preventDefault();
  addBookToLibrary();
  submit.reset();
  displayBooks();
});

// Display each book as cards

function displayBooks() {
  const currentDisplay = document.querySelector(".currentDisplay");
  currentDisplay.textContent = "";

  myLibrary.forEach((myLibrary) => {
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");
    currentDisplay.appendChild(card);

    for (let key in myLibrary) {
      const text = document.createElement("p");
      text.textContent = `${key}: ${myLibrary[key]}`;
      card.appendChild(text);
    }
    const readBtn = document.createElement("button");
    card.appendChild(readBtn);

    if (myLibrary.read === true) {
      readBtn.textContent = "Read";
    }
    if (myLibrary.read === false) {
      readBtn.textContent = "Not Read";
    }

    readBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (readBtn.textContent === "Read") {
        readBtn.textContent = "Not Read";
        myLibrary.read = false;
      } else if (readBtn.textContent === "Not Read") {
        readBtn.textContent = "Read";
        myLibrary.read = true;
      }
    });
    const remBtn = document.createElement("button");
    card.appendChild(remBtn);
    remBtn.textContent = "Remove";
    remBtn.onclick = remBook;
  });
}

// Remove book function
function remBook() {
  const findBook = myLibrary.findIndex((element) => element === book);
  const delBook = myLibrary.slice(findBook, 1);
}

displayBooks();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's give each Book object a unique property.

```
  // Object constructor
  function Book(title, author, page, read) {
    this.bookId = `book${++Book.id}`;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.page = page;
    this.read = read;
  }

  //static property
  Book.id = 0;
```

While rendering a book we use the bookId property as class name for the div. This will be used for deleting the element.

```
card.classList.add(`${myLibrary.bookId}`);
```

Inside remove book function, we find the book using bookId property. we use the splice method to remove an element from array. Then we call the remove method on div element to delete the div.

```
  // Remove book function
  function remBook() {
    const bookId = this.parentElement.classList[1];

    const findBook = myLibrary.findIndex(
      (element) => element.bookId === bookId
    );
    const delBook = myLibrary.splice(findBook, 1);
    this.parentElement.remove();
  }
```

```js
// Data inputs

let myLibrary = [{
  title: 'test',
  author: 'test',
  page: '123',
  read: true,
}, ];

// Object constructor
function Book(title, author, page, read) {
  this.bookId = `book${++Book.id}`;
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.page = page;
  this.read = read;
}

//static property
Book.id = 0;

// Add new books to library
function addBookToLibrary() {
  let a = document.getElementById('formTitle').value;
  let b = document.getElementById('formAuthor').value;
  let c = document.getElementById('formPage').value;
  let d = document.getElementById('formRead').checked;

  if (a !== '' && b !== '' && c !== '') {
    myLibrary.push(new Book(a, b, c, d));
  }
}

const submit = document.getElementById('submitInput');
submit.addEventListener('submit', () => {
  event.preventDefault();
  addBookToLibrary();
  submit.reset();
  displayBooks();
});

// Display each book as cards

function displayBooks() {
  const currentDisplay = document.querySelector('.currentDisplay');
  currentDisplay.textContent = '';

  myLibrary.forEach((myLibrary) => {
    let card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');
    card.classList.add(`${myLibrary.bookId}`);
    currentDisplay.appendChild(card);

    for (let key in myLibrary) {
      const text = document.createElement('p');
      text.textContent = `${key}: ${myLibrary[key]}`;
      card.appendChild(text);
    }
    const readBtn = document.createElement('button');
    card.appendChild(readBtn);

    if (myLibrary.read === true) {
      readBtn.textContent = 'Read';
    }
    if (myLibrary.read === false) {
      readBtn.textContent = 'Not Read';
    }

    readBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (readBtn.textContent === 'Read') {
        readBtn.textContent = 'Not Read';
        myLibrary.read = false;
      } else if (readBtn.textContent === 'Not Read') {
        readBtn.textContent = 'Read';
        myLibrary.read = true;
      }
    });
    const remBtn = document.createElement('button');
    card.appendChild(remBtn);
    remBtn.textContent = 'Remove';
    remBtn.onclick = remBook;
  });
}

// Remove book function
function remBook() {
  const bookId = this.parentElement.classList[1];

  const findBook = myLibrary.findIndex(
    (element) => element.bookId === bookId
  );
  const delBook = myLibrary.splice(findBook, 1);
  this.parentElement.remove();
}

displayBooks();
```

```html
<div class="header">Library</div>
<form id="submitInput" action="">
  <label for="title">Title:</label>
  <input type="text" id="formTitle" name="title" required />
  <label for="author">Author:</label>
  <input type="text" id="formAuthor" name="author" required />
  <label for="page">Page:</label>
  <input type="text" id="formPage" name="page" required />
  <div class="read">
    <label for="read">Read</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="formRead" name="read" value="" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Add Book" />
</form>
<div class="currentDisplay"></div>
```

Comment: This seemed to work, and the explanation is clear! One quick question, do you mind explaining this line here "const bookId = this.parentElement.classList[1];" Specifically, the [1] is where I'm a little bit lost. Thank you!

Comment: when `this` keyword is used inside an event handler, `this` points to the element which triggered the event. In this case this is a button element. We use the `parentElement` property to get the element which contains the button so it can be deleted from the page including all the book details. `classList` property contains all the classes by which the element is represented in html, a classList is an array like structure so we can get the element using the index.

Comment: try using `console.log(this.parentElement.classList)` before the line you mentioned to see what the classList property looks like.

Comment: that's what I figured initially, thank you again for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add specific ids whenever you add a new card. And call the card classes using querySelectorAll. That will return you a nodelist. Loop that nodelist and check if the specific id that you are click right now match with the looped element's id. If true, you can do your stuffs in that loop cuz whatever you're doing will only apply to the button that you're clicking.

I made a sample here. By the way, I used JSON to check the condition in string state.

```
   function remBook(obj) {
    let card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
    for(let x=0; x<card.length; x++) {
       if(JSON.stringfy(card[y].id) === JSON.stringfy(obj.id) {
        /* You can do your stuff here using index */
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xw26rbvc/

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I'm still a little lost. Could you explain a little more in depth?